# Work out the command line of a GUI operation?

Tags: scripting, gui

I am trying to script one repetitive operation within an open-source software, FSLView to be specific. The operations are extremely straightforward in the GUI, I mean just several clicks.

However, I do not know the corresponding commands with which I can script it. There is no documentation of the commands, because it seems that the developers do not expect anyone to automate this viewer software.

Does every GUI operation have its corresponding command line? If so, how should I work it out?

Comment: is there any debug output on X's tty? you can do `cat /dev/vcs[ttynum]` to check.

Comment: @mikeserv It seems that there is no such folder called `dev`. Is it a hidden folder or something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, not every GUI application interprets the commandline arguments/options, and many only have options for configuration or debug issues that are best set in the process of starting the application.

However there are several [GUI test/automation tools](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_GUI_testing_tools) (look at the automation column and Linux compatibility), that can drive your application.

For simple actions and especially for GUI apps usage that can be driven by keyboard shortcuts, you might want to look at [xdotool](http://www.semicomplete.com/projects/xdotool/)